# Does HTTP server open a separate new TCP connection to send a video file for a GET request recieved (if client clicked on a video link)?

Tags: http, tcp, video-streaming, client-server, wireshark

I want to identify the video streaming connection in wireshark while surfing various things at the same time. Even if we watch just one video on youtube, several tcp connections are opened (to fetch images etc), I am interested only those connection which is actually used for streaming.

I tried to find those connections using filters like

`http.request.method == "GET" && ( frame contains mp4 || frame contains mp3 || frame contains mkv || frame contains avi || frame contains 3gp || frame contains .webm || frame contains .flv || frame contains .vob || frame contains .mov || frame contains .wmv || frame contains .rmvb || frame contains .m4p || frame contains .m4v || frame contains .mpg || frame contains .mpeg || frame contains .3g2)`

I thought that the video streaming will be done on that connection on which client sent http GET /some/song.mp4 request. But it seems this is not the case. Now how can I identify streaming flow now. Any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: use something like httpfox in firefox, and watch the requests as you stream a youtube vid. as a quick/dirty test, streaming "The Martian" trailer shows multiple hits on "googlevideo.com", with a mime-type of video/mp4. probably more reliable to look for that sort of thing than just looking for the presence of "mp4" - that can show up purely by chance in any data stream.